# xcopy gives file not found error

Tags: batch-file, remote-server, psexec, xcopy

I am trying to copy a file from local machine to a remote machine and using xcopy for this in a batch file. However it is giving me error for file not found.

As per my research, syntax is fine and this is how it should be, but I'm unable to see why is it giving error.

```
Psexec @IPlist.txt -u ad -p P@$$ cmd /c xcopy "D:\IS\d.exe" /I "\\10.10.30.116\D$\"
```

**Error**
    File not found - d.exe
    cmd exited on 10.10.30.116 with error code 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually PSEXEC is not remote copying entity rather it is to execute the files.

Following code worked for me. for detailed discussion on its working please follow the link below.

```
net use Q: \\remoteserver\D$ /user:ad P@$$

copy D:\Idols\d.exe Q:\
```

https://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-copy-file-to-d_topic15137.html